# Apache OpenJPA patch for v2.2.0 for security bug CVE-2013-1768

Tags: openjpa

Am searching for patch fix on Apache OpenJPA v2.2.0 for security issue [CVE-2013-1768](https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10817) but couldn't find it. So, can anyone please help me with the patch on version 2.2.0?! Am nearing the deadline, any quick help would be greatly helpful and appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Alekhya

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to [download a 2.2.3 SNAPSHOT](http://openjpa.apache.org/downloads-nightly.html) binary. It appears that OpenJPA hasn't cut a 2.2.x release since fixing the noted security bulletin. Additional details on [CVE-2013-1768](http://openjpa.markmail.org/thread/pkpr4d5g2ygwr5o4).